# Running mqtt python script in PHP bluemix container

Tags: php, python, containers, ibm-cloud, mqtt

I am running a PHP code on docker container hosted in Bluemix. The PHP code calls a python script which is a MQTT based subscribe code. My idea was everytime the subscribed code gets MQTT message it will write the values to a text file. The PHP code will keep on checking every 10 seconds for new values in the file.
The VCAP_ENV variables are getting written correctly. However, the site does not load.

The python script executes successfully when i try it locally. So no errors there too.
My code is as follows:

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

if( getenv("VCAP_SERVICES") ) {


// get IoT service configuration from Bluemix


$services = getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
$services_json = json_decode($services, true);

$mysql_config = $services_json["iotf-service"][0]["credentials"];

$org_id = $mysql_config["org"];


$port = $mysql_config["mqtt_u_port"];


$username = $mysql_config["apiKey"];


$password = $mysql_config["apiToken"];


}

// set configuration values
$config = array(
  'org_id' => $org_id,
  'port' => $port,
  'app_id' => 'mymqttfinalservice',
  'iotf_api_key' => $username,
  'iotf_api_secret' => $password,
  'device_id' => '007',
  'qos' => 1

);

$file = fopen("VCAP_CONFIG.ini","w");


#fwrite($file,"[config]" . PHP_EOL );
#fwrite($file,"org =" . $org_id . PHP_EOL );
#fwrite($file,"apikey =" . $username . PHP_EOL );
#fwrite($file,"authkey =" . $password . PHP_EOL );

fwrite($file,"[config]" . "\n" );
fwrite($file,"org =" . $org_id . "\n" );
fwrite($file,"apikey =" . $username . "\n" );
fwrite($file,"authkey =" . $password . "\n" );


fclose($file);

$file = file_get_contents('VCAP_CONFIG.ini', true);
echo $file;



$command = 'chmod 777 /app/PythonSubscribeCode.py';
$output = '';
exec ( $command);



$command = 'python3 /app/PythonSubscribeCode.py 2>&1';
$output = exec ($command);
print_r($output);


$x = 1;
while($x == 1)
{
  $config = parse_ini_file('Data.ini');
  echo json_encode($config);
  sleep(5);
}

?>
```

Python Script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import os, json
import time
import configparser

# This is the Subscriber

settings = configparser.ConfigParser()
settings.read('VCAP_CONFIG.ini')

organization = settings['config']['org']
username = settings['config']['apikey']
password = settings['config']['authkey']


#Set the variables for connecting to the iot service
broker = ""
devicename = "007"
topic = "iot-2/type/DesktopApplication/id/007/evt/status/fmt/json"
#topic = 'iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json'
deviceType = "DesktopApplication"

clientID = "a:" + organization + ":appId"

print (clientID)

broker = organization + ".messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com"
mqttc = mqtt.Client(clientID)

if username is not "":
 mqttc.username_pw_set(username, password=password)


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
 print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
 print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))


def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
    global message
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.qos) + " " + str(msg.payload))

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
     writeData = msg.payload.decode('utf-8')
     parsed_json = json.loads(writeData)
     UDD = parsed_json['UDD']
     DDD = parsed_json['DDD']
     PH = parsed_json['PH']
     Ignition = parsed_json['Ignition']

     # add the settings to the structure of the file, and lets write it out...
     config = configparser.ConfigParser()
     config['Data'] = {'UDD': UDD,
                      'DDD': DDD,
                      'PH': PH,
                  'Ignition':Ignition}
     with open('Data.ini', 'w') as configfile:
      config.write(configfile)

mqttc.connect(host=broker, port=1883, keepalive=60)
test = mqttc.subscribe(topic,0)

#print (test)
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
mqttc.on_message = on_message

mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Can someone please guide on this?

Comment: I'm going to assume that the php build pack doesn't contain a python interpreter or any way to pip install the MQTT module

Comment: @hardlib It contains python interpreter. It does give other errors in case there are any. Also, if I try the mqtt code for PHP it works. However, I do not want to keep refreshing webpage that is why I opted for python implementation.

Comment: @hardillb Can the reason be that since Python script is a subscribe code it never exits the execution and hence the control never comes back to the PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any useful error messages from `cf ic logs containerid` to see what might be failing?  As an alternate, you could also try execing into the container (either `cf ic exec -ti containerid bash` or `docker exec...`) and run the python script directly to see if that's giving you other errors when running there.